# Convergence of a sequence in absolut value.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, proof-verification

I need to prove this:

If $a_{n}$ converges to $A$, then $|a_{n}|$ converges to $|A|$.

And I have this:

$a_{n} \rightarrow A$ then, given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N \in J$ such that 
$$|a_{n}-A|<\epsilon$$
for $n \ge N$.
Now, we consider the sequence:
$$\{|a_{n}| \}$$
And we claim that:
$$\{|a_{n}| \}\rightarrow |A|$$

Then using the reverse triangle inequality we have that:
$$\epsilon>|a_{n}-A|>||a_{n}|-|A||\\
\Rightarrow\epsilon>||a_{n}|-|A||$$

then we have that $\{|a_{n}| \}\rightarrow |A|$

Am I right?, and Is the converse true?, Why?. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You're right: just correct some typo! The sequence $(|a_n|)$ converges to $|A|$ if  $(a_n)$ is convergent to $A$.

The converse isn't true: consider the sequence $((-1)^n)$.

Answer (score 2):

You got it $99.99\%$ right: just note that $|a_n-A|\geq ||a_n|-|A||$ (note the weak inequality).

The converse is false: the alternating sequence $1,-1,1,-1,\ldots$ diverges but converges absolutely to $1$.

Comment: Thanks again @KimJongUn but how can I fix it?:)

Comment: You don't need to fix anything: $\epsilon>|a_b-A|\geq||a_n|-|A||$ implies $\epsilon>||a_n|-|A||$ as well.

Comment: Thank You @KimJongUn I am happy because of this improvement :)

Comment: Nice to hear. Good luck!